# Safe html in java

Tags: java, html, escaping, xss, playframework-2.0

I have some input containing `HTML` like `<br> <b> <i>` etc. I need a way to escape only the "bad" `HTML` that exposes my site to XSS etc.

After hours of Googeling I found the [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml) which looks kinda promising.

What is the recommended way to escape bad `HTML`?

Edit:

Let me clear things up.

I am using a javascript text editor which outputs html. Wouldn't it be much easier if i use something like bbcode?

Comment: Only the "bad" HTML? Or *all* HTML (the latter is easy)?

Comment: Only things like the <script> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/)  is a tool for making third party HTML, CSS and JavaScript ***safe*** to embed in your website.

Answer (score 2):

OWASP AntiSamy is a project for just that. If you need users to be able to submit structured text, look at markdown (imho a lot better than BBCode).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just escape all html. If you want to have users be able to use basic html tags like `<b>` or `<i>` then you could just replace them with [b] and [i] (if your forum/whatever you're creating can use bbcode), then just replace all `"<"` and `">"` with `"&lt;"` and `"&gt;"`.

Comment: what about `<    script>` tags :) ?

Comment: Do broswers render tags with whitespace in between them?

Comment: axl: yes they do. the question should be "what kind of crazy shit dont browsers render?" Browsers are pretty relaxed about what they render.

Comment: also there is `<script\n>' thats a newline right there. also will render that

Answer (score 1):

Playframework 2 already offers a solution.

the `@Html()` function filters bad html, which is really nice.

I really love play2